# How can I make this query to run faster?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query that runs very slow and I appreciate your comments to help me make this run faster. I don't have permission to alter any of the databases. I have two databases, 1 and 2.

Database 1 has the callers information including CallMemberID (could be less or more than 14 digits and could include comma), Vehicle properties (color, manufacturer, model, state, ..), and etc.

1. I removed the comma and then took the first 14 digits of CallMemberID as MemberId using: left(CallMemberID_mod,14) as 'MemberID'
2. I also cancatenated the vehicle properties as 'vehicle' to later find the number of distinct vehicles per MemberID using: Count(distinct(b.Vehicle)) as 'Vehicle Count per Member'
   Database 2 has information about those members that have made a complaint call. It includes clubcode, CallMemberID, and dait (its really the date the members have made a call). 
   I found the number of complaints per member using:   COUNT(*)as 'ComplaintsPerMemberId' group by MemberID
   and I also found the average number of days between calls per member id using: AvgCallTimes:

```
WITH CallTimesOrdered (num, id, calldate) AS 
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clubcode, CallMemberID ORDER BY dait DESC) AS RowNumber
            ,CallMemberID
            ,dait
    FROM    database1
)
,AvgCallTimes (id, timespan) AS 
(
    SELECT   CurrentDate.id
            ,DATEDIFF(d, CurrentDate.calldate, PriorDate.calldate)
    FROM    CallTimesOrdered CurrentDate
            INNER JOIN CallTimesOrdered PriorDate ON PriorDate.num = CurrentDate.num - 1 AND PriorDate.id = CurrentDate.id
)

SELECT   b.MemberID
        ,AVG(d.timespan) AS AverageTimeBetweenCalls
        ,COUNT(Distinct(b.Vehicle)) AS VehicleCountPerMember
        ,ISNULL(vic.ComplaintsPerMemberId, 0) AS NumberOfComplaintsPerMember
FROM    (
            SELECT   *
                    ,ISNULL(a.VehicleColor,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(a.VehicleManufactureYearDate, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(a.VehicleLicenseStateCode, '') + ' '
                        + ISNULL(a.VehicleManufactureNumber, '') +' '
                        + ISNULL(a.VehicleModelNumber, '') 
                    AS Vehicle
            FROM    (
                        SELECT   c.CallMemberID
                                ,LEFT(CallMemberID_mod, 14) AS MemberID
                                ,c.VehicleColor
                                ,c.VehicleManufactureYearDate
                                ,c.VehicleLicenseStateCode
                                ,c.VehicleManufactureNumber
                                ,c.VehicleModelNumber
                                ,ID
                        FROM    (
                                    SELECT   LTRIM(REPLACE(CallMemberID, ',', '')) AS CallMemberID_mod
                                            ,*
                                    FROM    database1 WITH (nolock)
                                ) c
                        WHERE   LEN(CallMemberID_mod) >= 14
                    ) a
        ) b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   tab.MemberId
                    ,tab.ComplaintsPerMemberId
            FROM    (
                        SELECT   clubcode
                                ,MemberId
                                ,COUNT(*) AS ComplaintsPerMemberId
                        FROM    database2
                        GROUP BY MemberId
                                ,clubcode
                    ) tab
        ) vic On vic.MemberId = b.MemberId
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   Id
                    ,timespan
            FROM    AvgCallTimes
        ) d ON d.ID = b.CallMemberID
GROUP BY b.MemberID
        ,vic.ComplaintsPerMemberId
ORDER BY b.MemberID
```

Comment: Can you show the query execution plan?  Without that it would be near impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: (1) i would like to suggest, remove * and take those many attributes which really used in your output. So many places, you have used '*'. (2) why don't you take distinct vehicle at inner query. Then you take count of it. try to use CTE @ taking count of ComplaintsPerMemberId. If vehicle select result lesser than 5000 rows, then try to make it @ table variable, as its resides in memory and give you fast output.

Answer (score 0):

trying to help you but cannot say how much increase the performance without running with actual data or without seeing execution plan.

```
Declare @MemberVehicle Table
(
     CallMemberID       Int
    ,MemberID           Varchar(500)
    ,Vehicle            Varchar(500)
    ,ID                 Int
)

WITH CallTimesOrdered (num, id, calldate) AS 
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clubcode, CallMemberID ORDER BY dait DESC) AS RowNumber
            ,CallMemberID
            ,dait
    FROM    database1
)
,AvgCallTimes (id, timespan) AS 
(
    SELECT   CurrentDate.id
            ,DATEDIFF(d, CurrentDate.calldate, PriorDate.calldate)
    FROM    CallTimesOrdered CurrentDate
            INNER JOIN CallTimesOrdered PriorDate ON PriorDate.num = CurrentDate.num - 1 AND PriorDate.id = CurrentDate.id
)

Insert Into @MemberVehicle(CallMemberID,MemberID,Vehicle,ID)
Select   a.CallMemberID
        ,a.MemberID
        ,ISNULL(a.VehicleColor,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(a.VehicleManufactureYearDate, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(a.VehicleLicenseStateCode, '') + ' '
            + ISNULL(a.VehicleManufactureNumber, '') +' '
            + ISNULL(a.VehicleModelNumber, '') 
            AS Vehicle
        ,a.ID
From    (
            SELECT   Distinct
                     c.CallMemberID
                    ,Left(LTRIM(REPLACE(CallMemberID, ',', '')), 14) AS MemberID
                    ,c.VehicleColor
                    ,c.VehicleManufactureYearDate
                    ,c.VehicleLicenseStateCode
                    ,c.VehicleManufactureNumber
                    ,c.VehicleModelNumber
                    ,c.ID
            FROM    database1 As c With (Nolock)
            Where   Len(LTRIM(REPLACE(CallMemberID, ',', ''))) >= 14
        ) As a

SELECT   b.MemberID
        ,AVG(d.timespan) AS AverageTimeBetweenCalls
        ,Count(b.Vehicle) AS VehicleCountPerMember
        ,ISNULL(vic.ComplaintsPerMemberId, 0) AS NumberOfComplaintsPerMember
FROM    @MemberVehicle As b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   tab.MemberId
                    ,tab.ComplaintsPerMemberId
            FROM    (
                        SELECT   clubcode
                                ,MemberId
                                ,COUNT(*) AS ComplaintsPerMemberId
                        FROM    database2 With (Nolock)
                        GROUP BY MemberId
                                ,clubcode
                    ) tab
        ) vic On vic.MemberId = b.MemberId
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT   Id
                    ,timespan
            FROM    AvgCallTimes With (Nolock)
        ) d ON d.ID = b.CallMemberID
GROUP BY b.MemberID
        ,vic.ComplaintsPerMemberId
ORDER BY b.MemberID
```